# Autoresizing KILabel in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, autoresize

I have a custom UILabel that I download from Github (called KILabel). The reason I got it because I wanted to duplicate Instagram's activity feed(The segmented control and the UITableViews with 2 different sets of information). In instagram's app I know there is the ability to tap on people usernames within the label that is contained in each and ever UITableViewCell(This is where KILabel comes into play). KILabel recognizes "@usernames", "#hashtags", and URLs and makes them tappable almost like a UIButton.

I had previously went without the KILabel and used the regular UILabel and it was able to expand in iOS 8 and iOS 7. Now, when I use the KILabel it auto expands(Dynamically changes its height to fit the text) **ONLY** on iOS 7 and it does **NOT** start off expanded. When I scroll in my UITableViewController, that is when the label expands. It starts off normal height.

As of right now this what the Custom Cell looks like

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "KILabel.h"

@interface NewsCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet KILabel *cellLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellImageView;

@end
```

I have the label in the interface(storyboard) hooked up to the custom KILabel class as well as the ImageView.

Next I have the cell being implemented in the UITableViewController. I tested it with a large piece of text to see if the cell and label would expand to the correct size

```
cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.cellImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
        cell.cellImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        cell.cellImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        cell.cellImageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];


        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
        longPress.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [cell.cellLabel addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
        //Create the cell label going into the cell
        cell.cellLabel.linkTapHandler = ^(KILinkType linkType, NSString *string, NSRange range) {
            NSString *mString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@""];
            if (linkType == KILinkTypeURL) {
                // Open URLs
                //[self attemptOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];
            } else if (linkType == KILinkTypeUserHandle) {
                if (longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible) {
                    [self tapOnUsername:longPress username:mString];
                }

            } else {
                // Put up an alert with a message if it's not an URL
                NSString *linkTypeString = @"Username";
                if (linkType == KILinkTypeHashtag)
                {
                    linkTypeString = @"Hashtag";
                }

                NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You tapped %@ which is a %@", string, linkTypeString];
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello"
                                                                message:message
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            }

            };

        PFObject *eachNews = [self.followingNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        PFUser *notifier = [eachNews objectForKey:@"Notifier"];
        PFUser *notified = [eachNews objectForKey:@"Notified"];
        [notifier fetchIfNeeded];
        [notified fetchIfNeeded];

        NSString *notifierString = [[NSString alloc] init];
        NSString *notifiedString = [[NSString alloc] init];
        NSString *grammer = [[NSString alloc] init];

        NSDate *timeStamp = eachNews.createdAt;
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy h:mm a"];

        NSString *timeString = [timeStamp formattedAsTimeAgo];

        if ([notifier.username isEqualToString:_loggedInUser.username]) {
            notifierString = @"You";
            grammer = @"are";
        } else {
            notifierString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@", notifier.username];
            grammer = @"is";
        }

        if ([notified.username isEqualToString: _loggedInUser.username]) {
            notifiedString = @"you";
        } else {
            notifiedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@", notified.username];
        }


        if (notifier[@"profileImage"] == nil) {
            UIImage *hermet = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user"];
            [cell.cellImageView setImage:hermet];
        } else {
            PFFile *imageFile = notifier[@"profileImage"];
            [cell.cellImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[imageFile getData]]];
        }


        NSMutableString *newsText = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        if ([eachNews[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"Follow"]) {
            [newsText appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasafsfsdgsdgsdfgsdfsodjnfsaioefgnarpuoigbweuifbsdpugbdsfiougbsdiugosbdgiusobfasdioFPBSADUBVSIUDVBSAIUDBSDIUVBSDUVIBDSFIUVBSDIUVSBAVIPUBDSIUVaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasafsfsdgsdgsdfgsdfsodjnfsaioefgnarpuoigbweuifbsdpugbdsfiougbsdiugosbdgiusobfasdioFPBSADUBVSIUDVBSAIUDBSDIUVBSDUVIBDSFIUVBSDIUVSBAVIPUBDSIUVaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasafsfsdgsdgsdfgsdfsodjnfsaioefgnarpuoigbweuifbsdpugbdsfiougbsdiugosbdgiusobfasdioFPBSADUBVSIUDVBSAIUDBSDIUVBSDUVIBDSFIUVBSDIUVSBAVIPUBDSIUVaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasafsfsdgsdgsdfgsdfsodjnfsaioefgnarpuoigbweuifbsdpugbdsfiougbsdiugosbdgiusobfasdioFPBSADUBVSIUDVBSAIUDBSDIUVBSDUVIBDSFIUVBSDIUVSBAVIPUBDSIUVaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasafsfsdgsdgsdfgsdfsodjnfsaioefgnarpuoigbweuifbsdpugbdsfiougbsdiugosbdgiusobfasdioFPBSADUBVSIUDVBSAIUDBSDIUVBSDUVIBDSFIUVBSDIUVSBAVIPUBDSIUVaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasafsfsdgsdgsdfgsdfsodjnfsaioefgnarpuoigbweuifbsdpugbdsfiougbsdiugosbdgiusobfasdioFPBSADUBVSIUDVBSAIUDBSDIUVBSDUVIBDSFIUVBSDIUVSBAVIPUBDSIUVaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasafsfsdgsdgsdfgsdfsodjnfsaioefgnarpuoigbweuifbsdpugbdsfiougbsdiugosbdgiusobfasdioFPBSADUBVSIUDVBSAIUDBSDIUVBSDUVIBDSFIUVBSDIUVSBAVIPUBDSIUVaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasafsfsdgsdgsdfgsdfsodjnfsaioefgnarpuoigbweuifbsdpugbdsfiougbsdiugosbdgiusobfasdioFPBSADUBVSIUDVBSAIUDBSDIUVBSDUVIBDSFIUVBSDIUVSBAVIPUBDSIUVaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasafsfsdgsdgsdfgsdfsodjnfsaioefgnarpuoigbweuifbsdpugbdsfiougbsdiugosbdgiusobfasdioFPBSADUBVSIUDVBSAIUDBSDIUVBSDUVIBDSFIUVBSDIUVSBAVIPUBDSIUVaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasafsfsdgsdgsdfgsdfsodjnfsaioefgnarpuoigbweuifbsdpugbdsfiougbsdiugosbdgiusobfasdioFPBSADUBVSIUDVBSAIUDBSDIUVBSDUVIBDSFIUVBSDIUVSBAVIPUBDSIUVaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasafsfsdgsdgsdfgsdfsodjnfsaioefgnarpuoigbweuifbsdpugbdsfiougbsdiugosbdgiusobfasdioFPBSADUBVSIUDVBSAIUDBSDIUVBSDUVIBDSFIUVBSDIUVSBAVIPUBDSIUVaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasafsfsdgsdgsdfgsdfsodjnfsaioefgnarpuoigbweuifbsdpugbdsfiougbsdiugosbdgiusobfasdioFPBSADUBVSIUDVBSAIUDBSDIUVBSDUVIBDSFIUVBSDIUVSBAVIPUBDSIUVaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasafsfsdgsdgsdfgsdfsodjnfsaioefgnarpuoigbweuifbsdpugbdsfiougbsdiugosbdgiusobfasdioFPBSADUBVSIUDVBSAIUDBSDIUVBSDUVIBDSFIUVBSDIUVSBAVIPUBDSIUVaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasafsfsdgsdgsdfgsdfsodjnfsaioefgnarpuoigbweuifbsdpugbdsfiougbsdiugosbdgiusobfasdioFPBSADUBVSIUDVBSAIUDBSDIUVBSDUVIBDSFIUVBSDIUVSBAVIPUBDSIUV%@ %@.\n", notifierString, eachNews[@"Messages"], notifiedString]];
        } else if ([eachNews[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"New Founder"]) {
            [newsText appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@.\n", notifierString, grammer, eachNews[@"Messages"]]];
        } else if ([eachNews[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"Club Create"]) {
            if([notified.username isEqualToString:_loggedInUser.username]) {
                notifiedString = @"You";
            } else {
                notifiedString = notified.username;
            }
            if (notified[@"profileImage"] == nil) {
                UIImage *hermet = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user"];
                [cell.cellImageView setImage:hermet];
            } else {
                PFFile *imageFile = notified[@"profileImage"];
                [cell.cellImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[imageFile getData]]];
            }
            [newsText appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n", notifiedString, eachNews[@"Messages"]]];
        }


        [newsText appendString:timeString];
        NSArray *appendedString = [newsText componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
        NSRange dateRange = [newsText rangeOfString:appendedString[1]];
        NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:newsText];

        [attrString beginEditing];
        [attrString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                           value:[UIColor lightGrayColor]
                           range:dateRange];

        [attrString endEditing];

        cell.cellLabel.attributedText = attrString;

        CGSize sizeForLabel = CGSizeMake(cell.cellLabel.frame.size.width, 0);
        CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(cell.cellLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.cellLabel.frame.origin.y, sizeForLabel.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);

        // Use a dummy label and its textRectForBounds method to calculate the height
        // of a real label.
        KILabel *measureLabel = [[KILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.cellLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.cellLabel.frame.origin.y, labelRect.size.width, 0)];
        measureLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

        measureLabel.attributedText = attrString;
        labelRect = [measureLabel textRectForBounds:labelRect limitedToNumberOfLines:0];

        cell.cellLabel.frame = labelRect;
```

The height of UITableViewCell is completely fine and expands perfectly. The label is the only issues. It does not expand at all on iOS 8 and expands **ONLY AFTER** I have scrolled in the UITableViewController on iOS 7.

I would tagged KILabel but I can't and if anyone has used another UILabels like KILabel and been able to get them auto-expand please refer me to them.

KILabel on GitHub: https://github.com/Krelborn/KILabel

Also, I have already tried the Gist the creator posted on his GitHub and that will get my cell to expand perfectly.

Comment: I'm using KILabel with Autolayout without any problems
Try to use autolayout instead of autoresizingmask

Comment: @ArnoldTang I actually fixed this. Not sure exactly what I did but it works perfecting right now. My views were created programmatically and I don't know/understand auto layout in code terms but I just `initWithFrame` to the appropriate size to the space that it is in with relation to the actually device size so it fits perfectly.